# Pyspark Column.isin() for a large set

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

Code:

```
views = sdf \
    .where(sdf['PRODUCT_ID'].isin(PRODUCTS)) \
    .rdd \
    .groupBy(lambda x: x['SESSION_ID']) \
    .toLocalIterator()

for sess_id, rows in views:
    # do something
```

`PRODUCTS` is a `set`. It is large, about 10000 items.

The code fails with:

```
--> 9 for sess_id, rows in views:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
--> 142         for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in load_stream(self, stream)
--> 139                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in _read_with_length(self, stream)
--> 156         length = read_int(stream)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in read_int(stream)
--> 543     length = stream.read(4)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    574             try:
--> 575                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    576             except timeout:
    577                 self._timeout_occurred = True

timeout: timed out
```

But when I make `PRODUCTS` set smaller everything is alright. I tried to change some timeout values in Spark configuration. It didn't help. How to avoid such crashes?

**UPDATE**

```
PRODUCTS = sdf.sort(['TIMESTAMP']).select('PRODUCT_ID').limit(10000).drop_duplicates()

views = sdf \
    .join(PRODUCTS, 'PRODUCT_ID', 'inner') \
    .rdd \
    .groupBy(lambda x: x['SESSION_ID']) \
    .toLocalIterator()

for sess_id, rows in views:
    # do ...
```

Now `PRODUCTS` is a dataframe. And I use `join`. Got the same error..

**UPDATE 2**

Trying this solution:

```
views = sdf \
    .join(PRODUCTS, 'PRODUCT_ID', 'inner') \
    .rdd \
    .groupBy(lambda x: x['SESSION_ID'])
views.cache()

for sess_id, rows in views.toLocalIterator():
    pass
```

After some time got a very long error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o289.javaToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:194)
....
```

This error appeared only once! Now I get the same timeout exceptions!

Comment: isin for a large dataset is useless complexity wise . Better perform a join or even something like try to get the element then true else false.

Comment: can you perform a count instead of `toLocalIterator` ? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to group `sdf` dataframe by `SESSION_ID` column and iterate over these groups. But I need to choose only those rows for which `PRODUCT_ID` is in predefined set. And `count` instead of `toLocalIterator` works normally.

Comment: ok and what about collect ?

Comment: `collect` instead of `toLocalIterator ` works. But if `sdf` is too large, I get `containers exceeding thresholds` error

Comment: Yes, I suspect that. So actually here is the thing. You'll need to cache that rdd before using `toLocalIterator` because this can create lots of spark jobs which may reside in recomputing the rdd many times which can lead to the error that you are getting. Tell me if this works so I can write an answer.

Comment: @eliasah, please, look at the update

Comment: @Leonidas I believe this issue is actually related to `toLocalIterator()` as documented in the answer I just posted. Can you confirm? I'd like to update the title to make it easier for future searchers to find.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to basically a bug in the implementation of `toLocalIterator()` in `pyspark 2.0.2`. You can read more here: [[SPARK-18281][SQL][PySpark] Remove timeout for reading data through socket for local iterator](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16263).

It seems the fix will be available in the next update after `2.0.2`and in the `2.1.x` release. If you want to fix it yourself temporarily, you can apply the changes from the issue above:

Replace this around line 138 of `rdd.py` (on the actual spark cluster, it seems you need to update the `rdd.py` inside `pyspark.zip`:

```
try:
    rf = sock.makefile("rb", 65536)
    for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):
        yield item
finally:
    sock.close()
```

with this:

```
sock.settimeout(None)  # << this is they key line that disables timeout after the initial connection
return serializer.load_stream(sock.makefile("rb", 65536))
```

Comment: Looks like the update has been released. I was having the same problem and after updating to 2.1.0 it went away.

Answer (score 0):

As @eliasah said in his comment. You should try join both DataFrames to exclude what is not in your PRODUCTS table.

```
views = sdf \
    .join(PRODUCTS) \
    .where(sdf['PRODUCT_ID']) \
    .rdd \
    .groupBy(lambda x: x['SESSION_ID']) \
    .toLocalIterator()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! But please make some efforts writing some explanation to your code and formatting it as well.